# Bootstrap navbar height

Tags: bootstrap-4, frontend

I have a question regarding navbar class, how can i should properly set height of the navbar?

lets have an example

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light" style="height: 30px">
 <a class="navbar-brand">
 <img src="source/of/the/image.jpg" href="#">
</a>
</nav>
```

this styling totally will destroy form of the navbar. Im unable to properly set icon to be exactly where I want it to be. Besides that, navbar-brand should be responsible for logo of the page but external configuration is not working as designed.

so I have two problems:
1. how to set properly height of the navbar
2. how to configure logo in navbar-brand that is compatible with parent navbar.

Comment: can you share a minimal code example which replicates the issue you face - that will make it much ore easier to help

Answer (score -1):

According to your example i have created a code example please follow the Link

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
  <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100X40" alt="" />
  </a>
</nav>
```

Visit Link : https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GAXG4ARRW8JB

- **Run code given link**

My Dear Friend i will suggest you that if you want to set a custom height you have to add class in **nav** for i.e,:  **custom-height** set your css custom style. I have added style in example link.